# How to append data to a sub-dictionary in a JSON file?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I want to add some Python dictionary into a JSON file and append into a sub-dictionary
This is just a template of what my JSON file looks like:

```
{
    "playerInfo": {
    }
}
```

Let's say I want to access the key "playerInfo" and append data, specifically another dictionary, into this JSON file. This would be a dictionary that I would append to "playerInfo"

```
"player1":{
    "name":"player1",
    "id":1
}
```

The end result that I am looking for would be to have this

```
{
    "playerInfo":{
        "player1":{
            "name":"player1",
            "id":1
        }
    }
}
```

And for any future data, I would append it after the "player1" dictionary. How would I be able to accomplish this?

Comment: I would suggest having a look around the internet first, before asking.

Answer (score 1):

If you started with this:

```py
x = {
    "playerInfo": {
    }
}
```

And wanted to add a player, do this:

```py
x["playerInfo"]["player1"] = {
    # Enter player data here
}
```

or

```py
x["playerInfo"]["player1"] = {}

x["playerInfo"]["player1"]["name"] = "player1"
x["playerInfo"]["player1"]["id"] = i
```

---

To append more keys:

```py
x["playerInfo"]["player1"]["<new key>"] = "<new value>"
```

---

And to add a new player

```py
x["playerInfo"]["<new player>"]["<new key>"] = "<new value>"
```

This code only highlights the fact that a new player is created by adding a `<new player>` key to the `playerInfo` dictionary.